# After upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10, themes and icons are missing

Tags: upgrade, themes, icons, 14.10

Was wondering if anyone has had a problem when upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 that their themes and icons are missing?

I am unable to change my theme via appearance app and most of the icons while browsing folders are missing.  I can still access the programs/docs through the GUI.  Seems to be just an appearance issue as everything else seems to be working properly.

I was watching the terminal prompt during installation and it did give a error while unpacking some items saying my installation may be broken.  I don't have a copy of the terminal text.  Anyways, I guess I'm asking what path would be missing that the themes and icons normally go into and how to repair that part of the upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Once you are booted up to your desktop... press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
apt-get install nvidia-prime

shutdown -r now
```

If issue persists, Try switching the terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then remove the configuration file `~/.config/dconf/user` like this:

(this action will remove your GNOME 3 settings)

```
sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm start
```

Hope this helps!